# Написать функцию указателя на положение последнего отрицательного числа

Tags: c++, указатели

мне дано условие:
Создать функцию для поиска положения последнего отрицательного элемента произвольного массива целых чисел. Вернуть указатель на отрицательный элемент.
Тестовая программа:

1. Создать и инициализировать 2 массива A[N1], B[N2]
2. Найти положение отрицательного элемента массива. Полученный указатель разделяет массив на 2 части.
3. Определить среднее арифметическое второй  части массива
4. Пункты 2 и 3 выполнить для массивов A и B

Помогите определить среднее арифметическое 2 части массива, пожалуйста.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <clocale>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <time.h>
#define  N1 7
#define N2 9
using namespace std;
void initmas(int* p, int n)
{
    int* tp;    // рабочий указатель 
    for (tp = p; tp < (p + n); tp++)
        *tp = rand() % 99 - 30;
}
void printmas(int* p, int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++, p++)
    {
        printf("%8d", *p);  
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int* minmas (int *p, int n)
{   int* tmin;
    int* tp;    
    for (tmin=tp=p; tp < (p+n); tp++)
        if (*tp<0) tmin=tp; 
    return tmin;    
}

int Fsred(int *p, int n, int c)
{
    int *tp;
    int sred = 0;
    for (tp = p+c+1; tp < (p+n); tp++)
    {
        sred = sred + tp;
    }
    int sred1 = sred / (n - c-1);
    cout << "Среднее арифметическое массива равно:" << sred1;
    cout << endl;
    return sred1;
}
int main()
{



int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    setlocale(0, "Russian");
    srand(time(0));
    int A[N1], B[N2];
    initmas(A, N1);
    cout << "Первый массив:";
    cout << endl;
    printmas(A, N1);
    int* q=minmas(A,N1);
    cout << "___________________________________";
    cout << endl;
    initmas(B, N2);
    cout << "Второй массив:";
    cout << endl;
    printmas(B, N2);
    int* q2=minmas(B,N2);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы бы как-то уточнили задание. Ну, хотя бы перепишите как задал препод, а не своими словами, потому что "*нужно написать функцию указателя на положение отрицательного числа*" yfpdfnm заданием сложно... А без точного ТЗ результат один — ХЗ... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask